# Getting DST for negative `time_t` in MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++14, dst, localtime

I am trying to determine whether a given `time_t` value is in DST for the given timezone.  So I wrote something like the following:

```
inline bool is_DST(time_t t) {
    struct tm* ti = localtime(&t);
    return ti->tm_isdst > 0;
}
```

This works great for current-ish times.  For example, on a current time_t value it returns `true`.  For the J2000 epoch, it returns `false`.  Nice.

Unfortunately, the MSVC variant of [`localtime(...)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf12f0hc.aspx) returns `nullptr` on negative input.  Reading the docs linked above tells me it also will fail after year 3000.  So, for example `(time_t)(-1)` (corresponding to 1969-12-31 23:59:59) will cause a segfault.

This is bad.  1969 wasn't that long ago.  Standard practice is to extrapolate UTC with the assumption that there are no leap seconds either before 1972 or anywhere in the future (until announced).<sup>*</sup>

What are my options to implement `is_DST(...)` that will work for the range of dates given by a 64-bit `time_t` (±2.9*10<sup>11</sup> years or so) based on above extrapolation?

<sup>*</sup><sup><sub>There's some question as to whether this is the right thing.  Leap seconds were introduced in 1972, and extrapolating UTC backward means you have to assume there weren't leap seconds (there would have been).  And extrapolating UTC forward is hard too, because Earth's rotation makes leap seconds unpredictable.</sub></sup>

Comment: If you don't mind keeping your own [time zone database](http://www.iana.org/time-zones) up to date, [@HowardHinnant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/576911/) has released a free C++11/14 [date library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date_v2.html) built on top of `<chrono>` and an accompanying [timezone db parser](https://howardhinnant.github.io/tz.html) with support for leap seconds.

Comment: @ildjarn:  If you'll make that an answer, I'll upvote it. ;-)  Admittedly it won't handle +/- 292 billion years range.  But it will handle +/- 32 thousand years range (not that this is meaningful, but it will do it).

Comment: @HowardHinnant : It only seems right to leave that to you. :-] @imallett, since you have this tagged `visual-c++` I assume using the Windows API isn't a problem, in which case [`SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724949.aspx) supports years 1601 through 30827.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the library ildjarn refers to in the comments:

https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date

It is open source and works on VS-2013 and later.  Here is how you would use it to implement `is_DST`:

```
#include "tz.h"
#include <ctime>

bool
is_DST(std::time_t t)
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using namespace date;
    return current_zone()->get_info(system_clock::from_time_t(t)).save != 0min;
}
```

This will work for negative `time_t`, but not for the full range of a 64bit `time_t` (which would be +/- 292 billion years).  But it will easily go back to the mid 1800's when uniform time was first introduced.

On Windows you will either have to install [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/), or manually download the [IANA timezone database](http://www.iana.org/time-zones).

If you would like to answer this question for some time zone other than the computer's current one, that is easy enough:

```
return locate_zone("Europe/Monaco")
                        ->get_info(system_clock::from_time_t(t)).save != 0min;
```

The range on Windows is `[-27258-04-19 21:11:54.5224192, 31197-09-14 02:48:05.4775807]`.  The restriction on this range is that this is the range of the VS `system_clock::time_point` (which has a precision of 100ns, and is stored as a `int64_t`).